# Upgrading theme to nopComerce 3.5 - Computer responsive theme

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, themes, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I am upgrading my nopCommerece site from 3.1 to 3.5, i have used "Computer responsive theme" and its available here  - http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/939/computer-responsive-theme-official.aspx

I ran all the upgrade scripts one by one i.e. 3.1, 3.2,  to 3.5. Admin panel of the site is working fine, but getting error at front end site - 
"The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController. "

How can I get the upgrade scripts for the theme -  "Computer responsive theme" for nopCommerce version 3.5 ?

Comment: this sounds like routing problem. your own plugins confuses with default routes I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This error is default nopCommerce error.
It's generate via auto testing.
Please check on your code.

Hope it's help for you